# Php global keyword replacing previous variable value with empty inside function

Tags: php, global-variables, global

I have to return some data by calling function, but global variable values we can't access inside function so I used global keyword,however after using global keyword it is making that variable empty,but I have to check condition by using that variable, so how to prevent variable values which is get replaced by global keyword,

```
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url = explode('/', $url);
    $url = end(url);
    $param='some_value';

    active(); // call active unction

    function active() 
    {
        global $url, $param;
      // after using global keyword  $url,$param values replaced with empty by global keyword     
    }
```

Comment: Rather than using `global`, pass in the values you need to do the processing and `return` the result.

Comment: sorry didn't get can you please explain by writing some code

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions/5166255.

Comment: Can't replicate https://3v4l.org/2kVWv

Comment: @Nick I am getting empty after using this,surprised....

Comment: Judging by your indentation, perhaps `$url` and `$param` are defined within another function? in which case you need `global $url, $param;` in that function too.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `$GLOBALS['url']` ,`$GLOBALS['param']`, your function returning empty because $url and $param are not declared inside the function, initially $url and $param are not global variable

Comment: global keyword is working hahaha, i think just put global on $url and $param outside the function

Comment: still getting empty, same issue

Comment: @Anonymous I have checked your code. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url = explode('/', $url);
    $url = end($url); // You miss `$` sign here.

    $param='some_value';

    active(); // call active unction

   function active() {
        global $url, $param;
        echo $url;
        echo $param;            
   }

?>
```

Comment: @Anonymous Your issue is you have not to get `$url, $param` value. Always return an empty value.

Comment: I want to access global values inside function and based on that compare them if they are equal then return 'active'